# Why does the box-shadow on a div disappear during a jQuery animation?

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

I am experiencing an issue when working with DIV-containers that have a box-shadow applied.
When I'm animating a DIV like that its box-shadow disappear during the animation.
[Here](http://goo.gl/rtUkQT) is an example what I'm talking about. Is it just me being dumb and doing anything wrong or is there a solution for the problem?

```js
$('#test').click(function(){
    $(this).hide("blind", 2500);
});
```

```css
#test {
    border: 1px solid black;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 1px black;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="test">This is a text.</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `.hide('blind', 2500)` causes jQUery to wrap the element with another `div` while it animates.

I'm not sure what your exact goal is, but you may consider using `.slideUp(2500)` instead:

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gewfajm3/2/

Answer (score 2):

Quoting Andi North above:

> It's because when jQuery animates the object, it sets overflow: hidden; on the parent .

Thus, I solved my case by setting `overflow: visible !important` to the parent container.

Answer (score 1):

It's because when jQuery animates the object, it sets `overflow: hidden;` on the parent `<div>`.

If you set your jQuery animation to be really long (120 seconds), and inspect the `<div>` you should see it setting the rules.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it inside another div with the right padding for the shadow. And .hide that wrapper div.
http://jsfiddle.net/PhilQ/gewfajm3/3/

```css
#test {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    padding: 20px;
}
#test div {
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid black;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 1px black;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 1px black;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="test"><div>This is a text.</div></div>
```